# Looping over array element produces strange value on last value of array counter

Tags: c, arrays

Right so i have this exercise i'm supposed to complete: [Exercise Specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwhfG.png)

And i'm having difficulty making sure the numbers in the array match up with the counter. The main issue is that on the last counter (49) there seems to be a number that isn't in the array. As you can see here:
[Output of current program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewjzx.png)

I am fairly new to C programming so I can be sure I'm doing something wrong, i'm just not sure what. Also how would I add the stars to match the lottery array like on the Spec.

Here is the current state of my code:

```
    int main()
{
        //char star;
        int i;
        int lottery[49] = { 23,16,18,19,26,13,22,    /*  1 ..  7 */
                            20,14,22,18,21,15,17,    /*  8 .. 14 */
                            24,15,18,20,13,14,20,    /* 15 .. 21 */
                            18,22,20,16,19,11,20,    /* 22 .. 28 */
                            16,28,22,20,15,17,17,    /* 29 .. 35 */
                            21,21,19,20,14,22,25,    /* 36 .. 42 */
                            19,17,26,18,20,23,12 };  /* 43 .. 49 */                         

        for (i = 0; i <= 49; i++)                   
        printf(" %2d  (%d)  |\n", i, lottery[i]);


    return 0;
}
```

Note: I've declared a variable for the stars already, but i'm just not sure how to implement it to the array to meet the specification of the exercise.

Comment: How many elements does the array have. How many are you printing

Comment: int lottery[49] declares an array with 49 slots, indexed 0 through 48.  you probably need to declare it as int lottery[50]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> for (i = 0; i <= 49; i++)

Array access out of bounds. When you have array like this:

```
int lottery[49];
```

you can only access elements with index [0,48]. Otherwise this is undefined behaviour and all bets are off. The bad thing is compiler might not warn you or report error in such cases.

Change to:

```
for (i=0; i<49; i++)
```

Comment: Right I see, well that seems to work now, but now the counter goes up to 0 - 48. And it says on the spec it needs to be 1 - 49. I'm trying to figure that out. I do understand that it counts from 0 first but is there a way to display that 0 as 1? and the same with the 48 appearing as 49?

Comment: @GR412 Depends how you print those stars. Just remember to stay within bounds of array - in the loop when doing printing you can assume that loop index i corresponds to i-1 th lottery number.

Comment: You have to change the `printf()` as well - see my answer below

Comment: @Giorgi Moniava Well the question has been answered and I thank you. I've learnt something so thats good. Now I need to figure out how I can use the star variable to reperesent the array values with ***'s

Comment: @GR412 Good luck with that

Comment: @Giorgi Moniava I don't know if if this is to much to ask, but i'll have a go at trying to figure this out, if I can't after a while would you be able to assist?

Comment: @GR412 Yeah but go ahead and try and you can always ask here once again - just make sure you show also some effort what you did. Hint: write a function which takes integer as parameter and prints out that many number of stars

Answer (score 2):

C arrays have 0-based indexing. For example, in your particular case, an array having 49 elements, you can have a valid access for index 0 to 48, inclusive. You should change

```
 for (i = 0; i <= 49; i++)
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < 49; i++)
```

Otherwise, you'll be [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) and thereby accessing out of bound memory. This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, `int main()` should be `int main(void)` to conform to the standard.

Answer (score 1):

In C (and many, but not all, other programming languages), arrays are 0-indexed, meaning that they start counting the index at 0.

This means that if you have an array of *N* elements, the last valid index is *N-1*.

In your case, you have 49 elements, but your loop condition is `i <= 49`, which means that you will try to read index 49 from your array. Since that's outside of the valid range, you're reading whatever value happens to be placed after your array in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 49; i++)
printf(" %2d  (%d)  |\n", i+1, lottery[i]);
```

This way you only run through the loop 49 times (remember arrays start at 0), and the `i+1` in the `printf` will fix the off by one error.

Comment: Oh thats great, that cleared up that minor issue. Thanks. I wish I could vote your answer up as well. but I can only choose one.

Comment: @GR412 You can vote all answers up. And you can always change which one you accept as your solution.

Comment: @StoryTeller it says I need a rep of 15 to vote up. So when I can i will.